# INSERT INTO no Postgresql com valores randômicos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Olá.

Meu problema é basicamente popular uma tabela no Postgresql com dados gerados aleatoriamente. Como os comandos SQL são um tanto extensos eu gostaria de ir complementando essa tabela aos poucos. A tabela possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| registro | nome |  CPF | localidade | cidade| email|
------------------------------------------------------
```

Para preencher a coluna registro eu utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
INSERT INTO data SELECT generate_series(100000,999999) AS REGISTRO;
```

Eu conseguiria por exemplo, preencher as duas primeiras colunas com o seguinte comando:

```
INSERT INTO data SELECT generate_series(100000,999999) AS REGISTRO, md5(random()::text) AS NOME
```

No entanto, como disse, meu objetivo é dividir os comandos em partes. Eu gostaria então de uma solução que com base no preenchimento da coluna REGISTRO eu preenchesse a coluna NOME. Ou seja, se existe um dado em REGISTRO então insira um dado em nome e assim por diante.

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO data(nome) SELECT REGISTRO,  md5(random()::text) AS NOME;
```

Mas o seguinte erro ocorre:

> ERROR: column "nome" of relation "data" does not exist

Alguém sabe uma forma de contornar isso?

Comment: Parece ser um problema para stored procedures, em que você pode por condicionais e loops (pro caso de popular)

Answer (score 2):

vc ja populou sua tabela o proximo passo seria alterar a coluna `nome`:

```
Update data set nome = md5(random()::text);
```

isso vai popular todas a linhas da coluna `nome` com md5 random text

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Sobre o erro, eu criei a tabela no pgadmin3 com letras maiúsculas bem como o exemplo mostra, logo a coluna nome tem de ser referenciada no comando SQL assim: "NOME", entre aspas.